# Goのテンプレートの変数をJQueryで取得したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, go

Goで利用するテンプレートでrangeの要素になっているものを取得したいです。例えば以下のような場合です。

```html
{{ range .}}
<li id="object">
  //このNameという変数をこのli要素をクリックした時に取得したい
  <p>{{ .Name }}}</p>
</li>
{{ end }}
```

このような実装は可能なのでしょうか、またできるのであればその方法を教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。HTML内でJQueryの`data`に変数を代入し、それをJQueryから参照することでGoの変数をJQueryに渡すことができました。

```html
{{ range .}}
<li id="object" data-name="{{ .Name }}">
  //このNameという変数をこのli要素をクリックした時に取得したい
  <p>{{ .Name }}}</p>
</li>
{{ end }}



var name = $('li').data('name');
```